# What is the best way to force a browser to retrieve a new SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, single-page-application

I have a weird scenario, I have a single page application that uses microservices that has multiple servers. We have a load balancer that will randomly change my server while I am still in my SPA session and this sometimes causes me to get SSL cert errors because of the load balancer switch. On my own I have been able to just refresh my browser to get the new cert, but for users, they wouldn't necessarily know to do that. I was thinking I could refresh the page automatically or give them a dialog to refresh the page, not ideal. My backend team has a ticket to try to get all servers to use one cert but it won't be done anytime soon so they asked me to look into a front end solution. I can probably just refresh the page but sometimes it takes a couple of refreshes before I get the new cert.

Is there a way on the front end to force the browser to get a new cert without a refresh?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are trying to address the wrong problem. The question is - why it gets SSL cert errors in the first place. For this to find out it would be helpful if you provide the exact details of the error, i.e. the full error message including any extended information from "Advanced" button in Chrome.

Comment: The load balancer switches which node I am connected to and the nodes have different SSL certs, the backend team has a ticket to fix this but in the meantime they want me to handle this in the front end - if possible. I understand that it's the wrong problem to solve and I've communicated that, but nonetheless it's been placed on my plate :)

Comment: Different certificates for the same domain is not an unusual setup by itself. This does not by itself  result in SSL errors. Something else is wrong here. Also - you still don't provide detailed error information.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Why would it not?  If the browser has cached the public key for one certificate, but is is now talking to another server with a different cert generated from the private key, this would be an error.  Kevin's team has moved on, but it would be nice to know if a) this was indeed the case, and b) if there was a convenient way to force a "reload" of the cert.

Comment: @GerardONeill: For a new TLS session the certificate is sent by the server within the TLS handshake - thus nothing to cache in the client here. For resuming an existing TLS session no certificates are used - thus no caching needed here either. What browsers sometimes cache are intermediate certificates but not leaf certificates. And this is only used in the case were the server fails to provide the proper intermediate certificate during the handshake, i.e. to work around broken servers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Very crisp explanation.  Which means he most likely had a bad cert / intermediary cert combination (one, or the other, or both, or the combination of both).  I've since learned that my issue isn't related to this, but its good to know.